# Rename Saved attachments with SenderName

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a VBA script to save all attachment to a folder. I am trying to rename the filename with sender's name. However when I tried this it changes the format of the files. How can I rename the files using the sender's name without changing the format of the file?

```
Sub Save_Mail_Attachment()
'''''Variable declarions
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim inb As Folder
Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim atch As Attachment

    '''''Variables Initialization
Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inb = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Specified Folder")
File_Path = "C:\Attachments\"

'''''Loop Thru Each Mail Item
For Each itm In inb.Items

'''''Loop Thru Each Attachment
    For Each atch In itm.Attachments
        On Error Resume Next
        atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & atch.FileName
        Debug.Print itm.SenderName

    Next atch
Next itm



End Sub
```

Comment: `.FileName` returns the extension for me. Have you confirmed that you are returning the extension with the `FileName` property in your code?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Option Explicit
Sub Save_Mail_Attachment()
    '''''Variable declarions
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim inb As Folder
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim atch As Attachment
    Dim File_Path As String '<--- missing
    Dim SenderName As String ' <------ Add

        '''''Variables Initialization
    Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inb = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Specified Folder")

    File_Path = "C:\Attachments\"

    '''''Loop Thru Each Mail Item
    For Each itm In inb.Items

    '''''Loop Thru Each Attachment
        For Each atch In itm.Attachments
'            On Error Resume Next
            SenderName = itm.SenderName '<----- Add
            atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & " " & SenderName & atch.FileName  '<--- Add
            Debug.Print itm.SenderName

        Next atch
    Next itm

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> Is it possible to omit the file name from being added

Yes, you could do something like this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Save_Mail_Attachment()
    '''''Variable declarions
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim inb As Folder
    Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim atch As Attachment
    Dim File_Path As String ' <------
    Dim SenderName As String ' <-----
    Dim Ext As String ' <-----

        '''''Variables Initialization
    Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inb = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Specified Folder")

    File_Path = "C:\Attachments\"

    '''''Loop Thru Each Mail Item
    For Each itm In inb.Items

    '''''Loop Thru Each Attachment
        For Each atch In itm.Attachments

            Ext = Right(atch.FileName, _
                            Len(atch.FileName) - InStrRev(atch.FileName, Chr(46))) '<----

            SenderName = itm.SenderName '<------

            atch.SaveAsFile File_Path & SenderName & Chr(46) & Ext    '<----

            Debug.Print itm.SenderName

        Next atch
    Next itm

End Sub
```

But remember if you get multiple Emails with attachments from same sender then you will end up overwriting existing file.

Comment: It works thank you! However is it possible to omit the file name from being added?